# How to find out the reason why ssh processes are hanging?

Tags: linux, ssh, strace, proc

When i run command like `iostat -dkx 2 2` via ssh, I get the expected result, but the processes on the local computer are saying alive in status "interruptible sleep". Why is this happening? Is there a way to find out the reason of that behavior?

full command:

```
$ ssh -o ConnectTimeout=4 -o ChallengeResponseAuthentication=no -o PasswordAuthentication=no <user>@host> iostat -dkx 2 2
```

ps output:

```
$ ps aux | grep 11893 && ps aux | grep PID
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
1000       10273  0.0  0.0 103280   904 pts/0    S+   12:09   0:00 grep PID
1000       11893  0.0  0.0 158732  3892 ?        S    Feb17   0:00 ssh -o ConnectTimeout=4 -o ChallengeResponseAuthentication=no -o PasswordAuthentication=no <user>@<host> iostat -dkx 2 2
1000       10285  0.0  0.0 103280   904 pts/0    S+   12:09   0:00 grep 11893
```

strace:

```
$ strace -p 11893
Process 11893 attached - interrupt to quit
select(8, [5], [], NULL, NULL^C <unfinished ...>
```

wchan:

```
$ cat /proc/11893/wchan 
poll_schedule_timeout
```

stacktrace:

```
$ cat /proc/11893/stack 
[] poll_schedule_timeout+0x39/0x60
[] do_select+0x6bb/0x7c0
[] core_sys_select+0x18a/0x2c0
[] sys_select+0x47/0x110
[] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[] 0xffffffffffffffff
```

Comment: I would attach the strace or gdb to the server process.

Comment: You mean on the remote side? Could you, please, tell me how i can do that?

Comment: @Shukov: I am unable to reproduce the error, you will have to provide some extra details, like: unusual configurations in `ssh_config` on client or `sshd_config` on server? Tiurin.

Comment: There were minor changes in the initial configuration related to configuring authentication. Such as PermitRootLogin or PasswordAuthentication.